# Javascript loop question : nested arrays access json hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, loops

i'm having trouble accessing the hierarchy of an api json which I am trying to loop through

This is my crazy nested json that returns from an endpoint:

If anybody has a suggestion about how to properly loop through this,  that would be amazing!!

```
'''{ "CVM": {
  "options":[
     {
        "symbol":"CVM",
        "id":"0M0205C200280P200V21",
        "expirationDate":"20200814",
        "contractSize":104,
        "strikePrice":22.9,
        "closingPrice":12.4,
        "side":"tpu",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":103,
        "bid":10.8,
        "ask":13.4,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-12",
        "isAdjusted":false
     },
     {
        "symbol":"CVM",
        "id":"00M0020002118VC020P0",
        "expirationDate":"20200809",
        "contractSize":103,
        "strikePrice":10,
        "closingPrice":3.2,
        "side":"tpu",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":73,
        "openInterest":801,
        "bid":2.7,
        "ask":3.5,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-18",
        "isAdjusted":false
     }
  ],
  "quote":{
     "symbol":"CVM",
     "iexRealtimePrice":15.47
  } }, "WLL":{
  "options":[
     {
        "symbol":"WLL",
        "id":"0P200008L00220010LW3",
        "expirationDate":"20200815",
        "contractSize":102,
        "strikePrice":3,
        "closingPrice":0,
        "side":"put",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":0,
        "bid":2.2,
        "ask":2.36,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-17",
        "isAdjusted":false
     },
     {
        "symbol":"WLL",
        "id":"2LL000P50W1700020800",
        "expirationDate":"20200730",
        "contractSize":101,
        "strikePrice":1.5,
        "closingPrice":0,
        "side":"upt",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":0,
        "bid":0.64,
        "ask":0.76,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-11",
        "isAdjusted":false
     }
  ],
  "quote":{
     "symbol":"WLL",
     "iexRealtimePrice":1.297
  }}}'''
```

the code i'm trying to use to loop through so far is this:

````
//example url
let url01 = fetch('https://sandbox.stockapi.com/options');
     
    
Promise.all([url01]).then( allData =>{
    allData.forEach(file=>{
       process(file.json());
        
    })
})

let process = (prom) =>{
    prom.then(data=>{


        // i can't get around hard coding the CVM below

        for (var i = 0; i < data.CVM.options.length; i++) {
           //console.log(data);
            let obj = {
            symbol: data.CVM.options[i].symbol,
            
            }
        } 
            
    })
}```
````

Comment: you just want symbol ?

Comment: i want to loop through something more like this:  data.[i].options.length    right now i'm having to manually do this chunk of code for CVM and WLL.   Does that make sense?

Comment: when i console.log(data.length);  i don't get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see here is that you supply a `JSON` object to process function, but it behaves as if the parameter is in `Promise` type. As far as I understood from your question, you do not know how many keys you are going to deal with (such as `CVM`, `WLL`). In that case, you can loop over the keys and find option for each one:

```
function process(data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        const options = data[key].options;
        // Do whatever you want to do here.
        console.log(options);
    });
}
```

Comment: You are amazing!  Thanks so much!   That totally worked!

Answer (score 0):

you probably want something like this

```js
q={ "CVM": {
  "options":[
     {
        "symbol":"CVM",
        "id":"0M0205C200280P200V21",
        "expirationDate":"20200814",
        "contractSize":104,
        "strikePrice":22.9,
        "closingPrice":12.4,
        "side":"tpu",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":103,
        "bid":10.8,
        "ask":13.4,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-12",
        "isAdjusted":false
     },
     {
        "symbol":"CVM",
        "id":"00M0020002118VC020P0",
        "expirationDate":"20200809",
        "contractSize":103,
        "strikePrice":10,
        "closingPrice":3.2,
        "side":"tpu",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":73,
        "openInterest":801,
        "bid":2.7,
        "ask":3.5,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-18",
        "isAdjusted":false
     }
  ],
  "quote":{
     "symbol":"CVM",
     "iexRealtimePrice":15.47
  } }, "WLL":{
  "options":[
     {
        "symbol":"WLL",
        "id":"0P200008L00220010LW3",
        "expirationDate":"20200815",
        "contractSize":102,
        "strikePrice":3,
        "closingPrice":0,
        "side":"put",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":0,
        "bid":2.2,
        "ask":2.36,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-17",
        "isAdjusted":false
     },
     {
        "symbol":"WLL",
        "id":"2LL000P50W1700020800",
        "expirationDate":"20200730",
        "contractSize":101,
        "strikePrice":1.5,
        "closingPrice":0,
        "side":"upt",
        "type":"equity",
        "volume":0,
        "openInterest":0,
        "bid":0.64,
        "ask":0.76,
        "lastUpdated":"2020-06-11",
        "isAdjusted":false
     }
  ],
  "quote":{
     "symbol":"WLL",
     "iexRealtimePrice":1.297
  }}}
  
   x=Object.entries(q).map(x=>x[1]["options"][0])
 console.log(x)
```